# How to import project's R in Live Template automatically?

Tags: android, android-studio, groovy, android-studio-2.3, live-templates

I'm trying to create a live template for Fragment's `onCreateView()`. This is my template now:

[image: Live Template]

After using it, `R` wants to be manually imported.

[image: Result]

How can I import application's `R` by default? Or can I somehow get the project package name with a groovy script and write it before `R` like `$PACKAGE_NAME$.R.layout.$LAYOUT_NAME$` to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enabling the "Add unambiguous imports on the fly" in File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Auto Import -> Java might solve your issue since it will automatically import the R class on the fly, and the need to manually import it will disappear.

Comment: Actually, it works for me! Even though the R import is definitely not unambiguous. Weird.